# WC: How can I search customer by billing_phone or billing_email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On create order page exist input for search customer.
This input searching customer by fields: 'user_login', 'user_url', 'user_email', 'user_nicename', 'display_name'

This is info present here:

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-customer-data-store.php

```
public function search_customers( $term, $limit = '' ) {
    $results = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_customer_pre_search_customers', false, $term, $limit );
    if ( is_array( $results ) ) {
        return $results;
    }
    error_log('search_customers NEXT STEP!!!');

    $query = new WP_User_Query(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_customer_search_customers', array(
                'search'         => '*' . esc_attr( $term ) . '*',
                'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_url', 'user_email', 'user_nicename', 'display_name' ),
                'fields'         => 'ID',
                'number'         => $limit,
            ), $term, $limit, 'main_query'
        )
    );

    $query2 = new WP_User_Query(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_customer_search_customers', array(
                'fields'     => 'ID',
                'number'     => $limit,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'last_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ), $term, $limit, 'meta_query'
        )
    );
    error_log('search_customers - WHAT IS IT?');

    $results = wp_parse_id_list( array_merge( (array) $query->get_results(), (array) $query2->get_results() ) );

    if ( $limit && count( $results ) > $limit ) {
        $results = array_slice( $results, 0, $limit );
    }

    return $results;
}
```

My question is: How I can add my own column to search_columns? I need to add column 'billing_phone' there.
During the experiment I changed in function search_customers(...) $query such:

```
$query = new WP_User_Query(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_customer_search_customers', array(
                'search'         => '*' . esc_attr( $term ) . '*',
                'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_url', 'user_email', 'user_nicename', 'display_name', 'billing_phone' ),
                'fields'         => 'ID',
                'number'         => $limit,
            ), $term, $limit, 'main_query'
        )
    );
```

This is not good way but I don't know how i can do it another.

But any way this "fix" not work.

How can I add my own column for search customer? Can i search customer by another column then present in search_customers(...)?

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to modify this search filter to be able to search by Client identity number. However, only by modifying original file. In such case, I had to disable WooCommerce updates.

So the first query
$query = new WP_User_Query() is looking for column values in wp_user table. However, the second query looks for column values in wp_user_meta. So in my case the code was as follows (where billing_cedula_ruc is one of the user meta that I save for each client):

```
$query2 = new WP_User_Query(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_customer_search_customers',
            array(
                'fields'     => 'ID',
                'number'     => $limit,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'last_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    // K&I add search by client RUC
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'billing_cedula_ruc',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            $term,
            $limit,
            'meta_query'
        )
    );
```

Comment: Okay, it turnes out that there is no need to modify core files. You can use a filter:

add_filter ('woocommerce_customer_search_customers', 'your_function', 10, 4);

function your_function ($filter, $term, $limit, $type){
     if ($type == 'meta_query'){
          $filter['meta_query'][] = array('key' => 'billing_phone', 'value' => $term, 'compare' 
           => 'LIKE');
    }
    return $filter;
}

Answer (score 0):

it doesn’t work(
In my case did next:

```
$query2 = new WP_User_Query(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_customer_search_customers',
            array(
                'fields'     => 'ID',
                'number'     => $limit,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'last_name',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    // Adding custom search by number
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'billing_customer_number',
                        'value'   => $term,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            $term,
            $limit,
            'meta_query'
        )
    );
```